# Will higher version Matlab work on windows 7 (32bit OS)

Tags: matlab, windows-8, windows-7, installation

Matlab has version 7 series (7.0,7.1 upto 7.14) and now 8 series. 
Someone told MATLAB 7.8 (R2009a) only works with windows 7 and higher matlab version will not work with windows-7 32bit OS. 
**Is it true ?** 
I am having windows-7 32bit OS. I wants to install recent version of Matlab software. **Which higher version of matlab I can install ?** 
And what about window-8 32bit OS ? 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true, the latest Matlab definitely runs on Windows 7 and much older Windows versions too: http://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/current_release/